# React binding "this" to external static method

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to bind "this" to an external static method? For instance, within a constructor of class A, declare `B.staticMethod.bind(this)`.
2. Is this normal practice?

Comment: What is your case? You can bind any regular function to `this` but it's unclear why this may be ever needed for another class' static method.

Comment: i dont want main class to grow too large, need to move some methods to other classes

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Doesn't look like a good idea. Why should `B` be a class and not standalone functions? A class shouldn't act as a namespace for a bunch of functions. Also, React favours functional composition, this limits reasonable options for class design. Consider providing real code if you need further assistance on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No you can't do that. Since it's a static method from another class there is no need to bind it. You simply call it like so: `B.staticMethod()`.
2. It is not a normal practice and you should never do that.

Comment: i need `B` to update the state of `A`. is there no "need" or no way to bind it?

Comment: No need to bind it. You should not use external methods to update a component's state.